# Start Fluidsynth at system start

Tags: startup

Does anyone know how to set up the control file so systemctl can start fluidsynth at startup.

I have wandered around in the weeds of the internet but cannot find a definitive answer. It appears that starting it as a user will accomplish this but I have not found any examples.

I am using Ubuntu Studio 21.04 (KDE)

Thanks... Tom.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `systemctl` is what you want. That one is used to start a service or some type of app that will run in the background. The majority of the processes started by `systemd` (which is what `systemctl` manages) are run by root, and only in special situations, they are run by the user.

I'm not familiar with *fuidsynth* but it seems that it's a program with a graphic interface, which `systemd` is not really your best option. I would suggest you use startup application, so your program will start after you've logged into your user's account.

Here's a link with instructions on how to do it on KDE (which I'm not familiar with, I use Gnome):
https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/autostart-programs-on-kde-plasma-5/

Comment: The comment to use the auto-start feature of KDE works.  The command

"systemctl --user start fluidsynth" did the trick.

However, I found that invoking QSynth, the GUI for FluidSynth also starts FluidSynth. 
Hence I do not need to start FluidSynth at boot, as I will also be using QSynth.